# Значение выходит за границы в цикле

Tags: c++

Вобщем есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
float wet = 0;
int count = 0;
while (wet < 5) {
    wet = wet + 0.1;
    count++;
    printf("Count equal %d\nwet equal %.4f\n", count,wet);
}   
}
```

Вопрос: Почему переменная wet выходит за пределы и становится равной 51, хотя тут нестрогое сравнение, то есть по идее она должна остановиться на 5.0 и count = 50, но при этом происходит еще одна лишняя итерация цикла

[image: Вот что выводит]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `float` - тип с ограниченной точностью. На самом деле на предпоследней проверке у вас в `wet` не ровно `5.000000000000000`, а что-то вроде `4.999999999999998`, но поскольку вы печатаете только 4 знака после запятой, значение при печати округляется до `5.0000` и вы этого не видите.

Поэтому числа с плавающей точкой обычно проверяют не на прямое (не)равенство другому числу, а проверяют вместо этого абсолютную разность между числами на то, что она достаточно мала (или достаточно велика).

Answer (score 3):

`float` и `double` значения надо сравнивать с некоторой точностью. Обычно рассматривают значения с некоторой малой границей эпсилон, с помощью которой эта точность и регулируется.

Answer (score 2):

в дополнение ко всем написавшим выше касательно `float`, `double` и вообще любого числа с плавающей точкой

во-первых в системе числа хранятся в двоичной системе, а это значит, что дробь, которая в десятичной системе является конечной, например

```
1/10
```

в двоичной системе будет бесконечной, потому что `2^x = 10`, где `x` - иррациональное число

поэтому, когда вы к конечной дроби добавляете бесконечную дробь, то результат будет представлять собой бесконечную дробь

`1 + 0.1 = 1.1` - конечная дробь только в десятичной системе, в двоичной системе она уже бесконечная дробь

а это значит, что вы **НИКОГДА** не сможете достичь числа `5` от числа `1` путем сложения бесконечных дробей

поэтому вам не повезло и число было `4,999999999`, а не `5` и на следующей итерации уже `5.09999999` или `5.100000000001`

Чтобы понять проблему, можно зайти и с другой стороны:

представьте дробь `1/7` - в десятичной системе это `0,1428571429` (пусть число хранит 10 разрядов после запятой), а в семеричной системе это уже точное значение `0.1`

и если вы решите сделать в десятичной системе

```
1 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7 + 1/7
```

вы получите `2,0000000003`

а в семеричной системе сделав тоже самое вы получите **строго** `2`

Comment: что такое бесконечная дробь и как она может быть в компьютире?

Comment: @300 bucks, бесконечная - которая содержит бесконечное кол-во цифр :), конечно в компьютере любое число ограничено, в этом и проблема, но я больше акцентировал внимание, что 0,1 - дробь которая в десятичной системе записывается конечным числом цифр, в компьютере точно может быть записано только бесконечным числом цифр, а ограничение числа таких цифр снижает точность со всеми вытекающими последствиями. Просто написал откуда она вообще эта погрешность вылезает казалось бы в конечных числах